# WCF Service calling another WCF service fails with web error 400 Bad Request

Tags: wcf

We have a web service that is called when user clicks save button on web form. The 'save' web service then makes a call into another web service (different machine).  The call always fails and as far as I can tell does not even attempt to cross the network because the Fiddler traffic is empty.  This problem only occurs when we call the second web service from the first web service.  If we call the second web service straight from the client or on page load, it works.  We are using WebHTTPBinding with REST type services.

I used the WCF trace to come up with the error 'Envelope Version 'EnvelopeNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none)' does not support adding Message Headers.', but I don't know how to resolve it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have just run into it and managed to fix with a change to the WebGet attribute on the service. What does your service signature including attributes look like?

Answer (score 1):

Possible fixes:

1. Check @ServiceHost directive( in
   . svc file) is set to
   "WebServiceHostFactory" [source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/39b3f522-2eeb-4ee2-a8ee-bdfe7c8d46bc/)
2. WebHttpBeahvior element is added in
   the endpoint behavior [source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/39b3f522-2eeb-4ee2-a8ee-bdfe7c8d46bc/)
3. Put ORDER information in the XML
   schema Class [source](http://www.pgs-soft.com/wcf-restfull-webservice-and-datacontractserializer-datamember-order-problem-deserializing-properties.html)
4. Check that your Data Transfer objects are
   serrializable [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808988/wcf-rest-client-exception)
5. Check if Skype installed and make sure it
   doesn't overtake the port
   [source](http://blog.kulov.net/2006/06/server-committed-protocol-violation.html)
6. Remove SOAP message header (it is not supported for REST
   WCF) [source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/39b3f522-2eeb-4ee2-a8ee-bdfe7c8d46bc/)